# Can some help to find here the syntax error?

Tags: mysql, sql

My MySQL query is this:

```
INSERT INTO CONTACTER_NOUS('id_contact',  'societe',  'civilite',  'prenom',  'nom',  
                           'adress',  'ville',  'code_postal',  'telephone',  'email',  
                           'comment' ) 
                   VALUES ('NULL',  'TCHAP',  '1',  'DIA',  'Mamadou',  
                           '27 av de foui', 'rueil malmaison',  
                           '92500',  '0611280444',  'dzdzdzd@gmail.com',  
                           'dzdzdz effef fefe feefefe')
```

MySQL responded with:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near
>   ''id_contact','societe','civilite','prenom','nom','adress','ville','code_postal','
>   at line 1

Comment: First of all please use english, many people on this website cannot understand french.

Comment: @dragon: its just strings. He could post `INSERT INTO A('b','c') VALUES ('d','e')` if he wants, as long as we're not supposed to know what it all means. And to find a syntax error, we don't... Offcourse, you are right that there are advantages to developing in English - but there are disadvantages as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Column names should not be in quotes.

```
INSERT INTO CONTACTER_NOUS(  id_contact,  societe,  civilite,  prenom,  nom,  adress...)
VALUES(...)
```

Answer (score 3):

Column names have the ` *(backtick)* sign around them, or nothing is fine too. Like this:

`` `column-name` `` or column-name

Answer (score 2):

Don't put single quotes around your column names.

Comment: Am sorry guys for the use of french... OK the problem was i thing due to quote in colonn names ;;t x all

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to change `'` to ` for your columns or just remove them completely and have just the column name.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
INSERT INTO CONTACTER_NOUS (`id_contact`,  `societe`,  `civilite`,  `prenom`,  `nom`,  
                           `adress`,  `ville`,  `code_postal`,  `telephone`,  `email`,                       `comment` ) 
                   VALUES (NULL,  'TCHAP',  '1',  'DIA',  'Mamadou',  
                           '27 av de foui', 'rueil malmaison',  
                           '92500',  '0611280444',  'dzdzdzd@gmail.com',  
                           'dzdzdz effef fefe feefefe')
```